# How to insert a ContentControl inside another ContentControl in word using Javascript Api

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins, javascript-api-for-office

I need to insert a contentControl that will contain a table and wrap this ContentControl inside another parent contentControl. Currently contentControl that contain table data inserted correctly but when i tried to get the current selection and inserting the CC, word showing message 'Rich Text control can not inserted around multiple selection'.
Please advice how i can insert CC and wrap inside another parent CC. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it on the selection. Get the range of the content control wrapping the table and then insert another wrapper.
like this:

```js
function insertTableWrappedBy2CCs() { 
     Word.run(function (context) {
          // We need a 2D array to hold the initial table values
          var data = [["Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple"],["Tokyo","Beijing", "Seattle"]];
          var table = context.document.body.insertTable(3, 3, "start", data);
          table.styleBuiltIn = Word.Style.gridTable5Dark_Accent2;
          var myCC = table.insertContentControl();
          myCC.title = "table";
          var cc2 = myCC.getRange().insertContentControl();
          cc2.title = "parent";
         return context.sync()
     })
     .catch(function (e) {
             console.log(e.message);
              })
     }
```

thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks, It working to wrap the cc inside another. If i need to insert the cc inside another cc, do i still get the range?

I need to insert some text in cc(A) and then put cc(B) inside it, like:
(A
  Some Text
  (B Some Text)
)
Please advice, Thanks.

Comment: @Amit did you find any similar scenario working example